# How to get value inside transaction result Firebase via node js

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an iOS messenger app using Swift, Firebase and Nodejs.

My Goal: 
Whenever a user sends a message and writes message data (such as senderId, receiverId, messageText) into a Firebase database inside node (/messages/{pushId}/), I want to make a message count increment by 1 using a transaction method that Firebase provides and display a notification to a receiver user.

Progress I've made so far and Problem I'm facing:
I've successfully increment message count (totalCount) using transaction method but I can't get value inside transaction result (Here's image of functions log )

[image: a busy cat]

I want to get "value_: 1"( this is the incremented message count) inside snapshot and put it to a badge parameter.

```
exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/')
 .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

const fromId = snapshot.val().fromId;
const toId = snapshot.val().toId;
const messageText = snapshot.val().messageText;

console.log('User: ', fromId, 'is sending to', toId);

return admin.database().ref('/users/' + toId).once('value').then((snap) => {
  return snap.val();

}).then((recipientId) => {
  return admin.database().ref('/users/' + fromId).once('value').then((snaps) => {
    return snaps.val();

  }).then((senderId) => {
    return admin.database().ref('/user-messages/' + toId + '/totalCount').transaction((current) => {
      return (current || 0) + 1
    }).then((readCount) => {

      console.log('check readCount:', readCount);

      var message = {

       data: {
         fromId: fromId,
         badge: //I want to display the message count here
       },

       apns: {
         payload: {
           aps: {
             alert: {
               title: 'You got a message from ' + senderId.username,
               body: messageText
             },

             "content-available": 1
           }
         }
       },

       token: recipientId.fcmToken
     };

     return admin.messaging().send(message)
     }).then((response) => {
           console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
           return response;
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.log('Error sending message:', error);
           //throw new error('Error sending message:', error);
         })
     })
   })
})
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation for [transaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) suggests that the promise from the transaction will receive an object with a property `snapshot` with the snapshot of the data that was written at the location of the transaction.  So:

```
admin.database.ref("path/to/count")
.transaction(current => {
    // do what you want with the value
})
.then(result => {
    const count = result.snapshot.val();  // the value of the count written
})
```

Comment: thanks! it worked like a charm! btw, I love your Firebase series on youtube